# Loopback 4 Content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded does not match [application/json]

Tags: loopback4

I am trying to add a payment gateway in my app. The scene is payment gateway posts some data to the controller. But while posting it is showing following error

```
> UnsupportedMediaTypeError 415 Content-type
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded does not match [application/json].
> code: UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
```

controller

```
export interface payment {
  razorpay_order_id: string;
  razorpay_payment_id: string;
  razorpay_signature: string;
}

    @post('/payment-check', {
        responses: {
          '200': {
            description: 'Verify signature',
          },
        },
      })

    async check(
        @requestBody({}) options: payment, @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response
      ): Promise<any> {

        // some code
          response.redirect('http://192.168.43.147:8100/order-success/?' + query)

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to specify the requestbody content-type to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
 async check(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded': {
          schema: { type: 'object' },
        }
      }
    }) options: payment, @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response
  ): Promise<any>
```